# NSImage different size in code different shown by Finder/Preview

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

I have a couple of images that i use in my application(one of them is attached). The strange thing is that the real image size(shown by finder and preview) is 1200x701 px.

When I access image from the code and as for its size, I get 360x210px. What is going on?

Code I'm using to get the size of the image:

```
NSImage *newImg =  [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                   [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:[sender draggingPasteboard]]];
float h = [newImg size].height; //height is 210px - should be 701px
float w = [newImg size].width;  //width is 320px - should be 1200px
```

The content of the newImg is the same image that has been pointed and loaded - I display it in the NSImageView anyway so I see. Just the size taken with `-size` is wrong.

This is the image:

[alt text http://www.tomaszkrasnyk.yoyo.pl/image.jpg](http://www.tomaszkrasnyk.yoyo.pl/image.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that -[NSImage size] returns the size in points, not pixels.  That's why NSImageRep has both a size method and pixelsHigh and pixelsWide methods.  Your image is apparently not at a 72 dpi resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSImageRep *imgRep = [NSImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
int imageWidth = (int)[imgRep pixelsWide];
int imageHeight = (int)[imgRep pixelsHigh];
imgRep = nil;

NSLog(@"original image width: %d",imageWidth);
NSLog(@"original image height: %d",imageHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

An `NSImage` can contain multiple representations of the same image, each at different sizes.  I'd take a look at the `-representations` method on `NSImage`, and then take a look at each `NSImageRep` object returned in the array to see what all it has.